# Tkinter - definir master em outro scritp

Tags: python, tkinter

estou criando uma GUI com Tkinter e estou tendo problemas ao separar as funções do arquivo principal (pois está ficando muito grande).

Criei um novo arquivo de funções, quando tento importar a função criadora de uma nova tela (Toplevel) recebo o erro de que a janela mãe (master) não é reconhecida:

```
consumeScreen = Toplevel(mainScreen)

NameError: name 'mainScreen' is not defined
```

segue o código da primeira tela:

```
from tkinter import *
import funções as fc

mainScreen = Tk()
mainScreen.geometry('600x415')
mainScreen.title('System')
mainScreen['bg'] = 'black'

fc.consume()
```

Agora a função construtora que está em um 2° arquivo chamado 'funções':

```
def consume():
    consumeScreen = Toplevel(mainScreen)
    consumeScreen.geometry('500x500')
    consumeScreen.title('Report Consume')
```

**Como faço para que o segundo arquivo reconheça o nome da tela inicial (mainScreen)?**

Answer (score 1):

Não dá para você simplesmente jogar uma variável do arquivo `.py` que está em execução para um arquivo importado. Para solucionar o problema, você pode passar `mainScreen` como argumento da função `consume`. Exemplo:

## Segundo arquivo .py

```
def consume(mainScreen):
    consumeScreen = Toplevel(mainScreen)
    consumeScreen.geometry('500x500')
    consumeScreen.title('Report Consume')
```

## Script .py que será executado.

```
from tkinter import *
import funções as fc

mainScreen = Tk()
mainScreen.geometry('600x415')
mainScreen.title('System')
mainScreen['bg'] = 'black'

fc.consume(mainScreen)
```

Comment: Não funciona pois o parametro command setado com a função dentro de um botão, não aceita argumentos: 
bt_Consume = Button(text = 'Report Consume', command = fc.consume)

Comment: Você pode por favor deixar todo o código para eu conseguir lhe ajudar ?

Comment: O código todo é muito grande, impossibilita o compartilhamento. Consegui resolver criando uma função menor que só importa a função construtora (onde há todo o código da nova janela). Creio que não seja a melhor solução, mas funcionou.

Comment: Para o código que você apresentou na pergunta, a única forma de correção é essa que coloquei na resposta. Mas outras partes do seu código aparentemente possuem alguns problemas como você disse no comentário acima. Esse parâmetro "command" por exemplo, eu nem sabia da existência dele.

Comment: Esse parametro é do tkinter para botões, onde eu passo uma função que será executada ao apertar o botão, porém, essa função não pode receber nenhum parametro. Por isso a solução que encontrei é criar uma função menor, responsável por chamar a função principal (que constroi a tela do app) e passa-la ao parametro command. Mas obrigado pela ajuda!